# Column conditions in dataframe groups

Tags: python, pandas

```
       A     B     C     D
0    Red  10.0  11.5  12.0
1    Red  10.5  11.5  12.0
2    Red  11.0  11.5  12.0
3    Red  12.0  11.5  12.0
4  White  10.0  10.5  11.0
5  White  10.5  10.5  11.0
6  White  11.0  10.5  11.0
7  White  12.0  10.5  11.0
```

I want to create a new df1, with next conditions:

Per each A group ("Red" and "White"):

- If C value exists in B group, take the row in which C=B.
- If C value doesn´t exist in B group, take the row in which D=B.

I mean, the new df1 should be:

```
       A     B     C     D
3    Red  12.0  11.5  12.0
5  White  10.5  10.5  11.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and for default ordering add [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
m1 = df['B'] == df['C']
m2 = df['B'] == df['D']
df = pd.concat([df[m1], df[m2]]).drop_duplicates('A').sort_index()
print (df)
       A     B     C     D
3    Red  12.0  11.5  12.0
5  White  10.5  10.5  11.0
```

Comment: Ok. And if I wanted to add a df["E"] with the value selected?  [{"A": "Red", 'B': 12.00, "C": 11.50, "D": 12.00, "E": 12.00}, {"A": "White", 'B': 10.50, "C": 10.50, "D": 11.00, "E": 10.50}]

Comment: @Tie_24 - Question is about selecting if multiple match. Now because `pd.concat([df[m1], df[m2]]).drop_duplicates('A')` are used first values of `m1` and then `m2` if match both. So if use `m3 = df['B'] == df['E']`, `pd.concat([df[m1], df[m2], df[m3]]).drop_duplicates('A')` then `E` lowest priority if match in all conditions, also `m2` has hight priority as `m3`